# Using loop to insert values from one table to another

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following table named `screening_plan`:

```
plan_id movie_id  plan_start_day  plan_end_day plan_min_start_hh24  plan_max_start_hh24 screenings
    1    1        1/06/2015       28/06/2015       9                  17                  5 
    2    2        1/06/2015       28/06/2015       9                  22                  4 
    3    3        1/06/2015       28/06/2015       9                  22                  5 
    4    4        1/06/2015       28/06/2015       9                  17                  4
```

And another tables `theatre`:

```
THEATRE_ID THEATRE_DESCRIPTION THEATRE_TOTAL_ROWS
         1                            2
         2                            2
         3                            3
         4                            2
```

There is a total of 18 screenings per day. I have to insert the details in the `screening` table as follows:

```
screening_id    plan_id theatre_id  screening_date  screening_start_hh24    screening_start_mm60
     1             1      3          1/06/2015          9                       0
     2             1      3          1/06/2015          11                      30
     3             1      3          1/06/2015          14                      0
     4                               1/06/2015
```

`plan_id` is a foreign key referring table `screening` and `theatre_id` is a foreign key referring table `theatre`.

- Each movie should be screened as per the screening number is defined
  in the table `screening_plan`.
- There is a break of 30 minutes between 2 consecutive screenings in
  the same theatre.
- The `screening_start_hh24` should be less than `plan_max_start_hh24`.
- Please note that the number of screenings for the first movie won't
  fit into the provided time interval,so the second screening should be done
  in an alternate theatre(preferably in `theatre_id=2` starting from 11:30).
- Each movie has a lenght of 2 hours.

I am stuck with this since yesterday. Tried doing it using the If-Else block, but that requires defining every condition. How can I do this using a loop?Please help.

My code(I have skipped the declaration part here):

```
 BEGIN

  SELECT plan_id INTO s_plan_id FROM  screening_plan  WHERE plan_id=1;
  SELECT theatre_id INTO s_theatre_id FROM theatre WHERE theatre_id=1;
  SELECT PLAN_START_DATE INTO s_screening_date FROM screening_plan WHERE plan_id=1;
  SELECT Count(*) INTO s_count_theatre_id FROM screening;

  IF s_count_theatre_id = 0
  THEN
    s_screening_start_hh24:=9;
    s_screening_start_mm60:=0;

  ELSIF s_count_theatre_id >0 AND  s_count_theatre_id <=4
  THEN
         s_screening_start_hh24:=11 ;
         s_screening_start_mm60:=30 ;
    ELSE 
      Dbms_Output.put_line('---');
  END IF; 

  INSERT INTO screening (plan_id, theatre_id, screening_date, screening_start_hh24, screening_start_mm60)
  VALUES( s_plan_id,
  s_theatre_id,
  s_screening_date,
  s_screening_start_hh24,
  s_screening_start_mm60);

END;
```

There should be a total of 18 record in the table `screening`.5 for `movie_id=1`, 4 for `movie_id=2`, 5 for `movie_id=3` and 4 for `movie_id=3`.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Which table should be filled with a records?

Comment: Would you mind posting DDLs and DMLs along with the PL/SQL code you have already tried?

Comment: what do you want exactly ? :s

Comment: Generally speaking this rather looks like something where you do not need PL/SQL at all and only use a single "INSERT INTO screening ... SELECT ... FROM ..." statement.

Comment: Please see the edited version.